# Tkinter Input Substitutions

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I've been working on a text based game in Tkinter, and I need a way so as to allow more flexibility with input. Basically, what I'm looking for is how to code:

```
if Input.get() == "look at" Item:
    Item.look()
```

But with the flexibility of 'item' being a class, with subclasses, all of which can be 'looked at'. This is my current (non-working) code for this segment:

```
def Check():
    if Output == "look at" Item:
        Item.look()
    else:
        pass
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, description, value, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

    def look(self):
        Look.Title = "{}".format(self.name)
        Look.Description = "{}".format(self.Description)
        Look.Value = "{} is worth {}.".format(self.name, self.value)
        Details.insert(Look.Title)
        Details.insert(Look.Description)
        Details.insert(Look.Value)
        Details.insert(Look.Quantity)
class Headphones(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__(name = "Headphones", description = "A set of high quality white headphones.", value = 150)
```

Any help is much appreciated,
Blaze

Comment: What do you think this does: `if Input.get() == "look at" Item:`? That's invalid syntax, and I can't guess what you think the `Item` part is doing. Are you wanting it to be concatenated with "look at"? Are you asking how to convert the user's input of `"look at headphones"` to run the code `headphones.look()`

Comment: I tried it like that because there's some other code (that I've forgotten) that works like that. For some reason. And, I'm asking how to convert a user input of "look at headphones" to run headphones.look(), or "look at goggles" to run goggles.look(), or "look at phone" to run phone.look(), etc, so it can run on any item.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some sort of mapping between the input and the functions you want to call. You will need to parse the string in order to pull out the object from the input string and use the result of the parsing to look up the proper object or class.

For example, you could use a regular expression to parse the string "look at X", and then use "X" as an index into a dictionary in order to know what class to instantiate.

Here's a simple example:

```
import re

class Headphones(object):
    def look(self):
        print("you are looking at headphones")

class Goggles(object):
    def look(self):
        print("you are looking at goggles")

class Unknown(object):
    def look(self):
        print("I don't know what you're looking at")

def check(input):
    map = {
        "goggles": Goggles,
        "headphones": Headphones,
    }

    match = re.match(r'look at (.*)', input)
    if match:
        thing = match.group(1)
        cls = map.get(thing, Unknown)
        object = cls()
        object.look()

for phrase in ("look at headphones", 
               "look at goggles", 
               "look at something else"):
    check(phrase)
```

Note: this is one of many ways to solve the problem. The point is, you need to:

1. write a parser that can pull out the important parts from the input, and
2. use the result of the parsing stage to decide how to process the data

The parser can be anything from simply splitting the input on spaces and grabbing the last word, to using a regular expression, to using a full blown parser using something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).